# Relay based Pagination in Java for Java-GraphQL server

Tags: java, pagination, graphql, relay, graphql-java

I have implemented a java based GraphQL server using the [GraphQL-Java-tools](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-tools). Now I need to implement the Relay based pagination with the Java-GraphQL server that I have.

I couldn't find anything helpful out there. Can anyone please help me in pointing out to the right place to find how to implement Relay based Pagination in Java_GraphQL server?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[graphql-java-tools](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools) added support for Relay in release [5.4.0](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools/releases/tag/v5.4.0). As explained in the [documentation example](https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/relay/) you can use the new `@connection` directive in the schema:

```
type Query {
    users(first: Int, after: String): UserConnection @connection(for: "User")
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
}
```

and return a `Connection<T>` in the resolver:

```
class QueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

  public Connection<User> users(int first, String after, DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
    return new SimpleListConnection<>(Collections.singletonList(new User(1L, "Luke"))).get(env);
  }
}
```

Still, examples beyond a simple list (eg. when edges have to be fetched from a database) are scarce, and `SimpleListConnection` is the only implementation provided by [graphql-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java) so far.

Comment: ...and that's quite a pity because this `SimpleListConnection` expects you to provide the whole list of the enclosed entities... which is uppermost counterproductive in terms of requesting the database!!